# h2 doesn't start programmatically

Tags: java, h2, h2db

I have wrote following code:

```
  private static void startH2(){
        Server server = null;
        try {
            server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.
                    getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL", "sa", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while initialize", e);
        }
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        startH2();
    }
```

I run my main method and see following situation:

[image]

Looks like `Server.createTcpServer` creates new non daemon thread.

but by url `localhost:8082` I don't see h2 web console(actual result - `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`)

How to fix this?

### P.S.

I have noticed that by url

```
http://localhost:9092/
```

my browser downlods file with strange content:

[image]

if to decode this text I see following message:

> Version mismatch, driver version is “0” but server version is “15”

I use h2 version `1.4.182`

Comment: @Antoniossss no, I run in run mode(not debug)

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't understand what do you suggest  to suspend

Comment: Sorry iv missread your post about NON deamon threads ;)

Comment: You probably have to do something in main to keep the program alive. What are you trying to achieve (ie. what is the purpose of this program)?

Comment: @RC. program is alive. I want to acheve that after code execution by url http://localhost:9092/ h2 web console be availble

Comment: the "strange content" in your browser actually says _Version mismatch, driver exception[...] at org.h2.message.DbException[...] at java.lang.Thread.run[...]_  - what's the actual java code you're running?

Comment: How about [using `java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server`](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server)?

Comment: @greenSocksRock I provided actual java code in the topic

Comment: @RC. I need to start h2 from java code

Comment: @Funtik no exceptions I see

Comment: @greenSocksRock How did you ynderstand it ?  version of what mismatch?

Comment: look closely at the screenshot - next to every `NUL` is a single character; if you ignore the `NUL`, it spells out the message I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[H2 contains multiple servers](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server):

- [the TCP Server](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#createTcpServer_String...) (for H2 JDBC clients),
- [the Web Server](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#createWebServer_String...) (for browsers, the H2 Console application), and
- [the PG Server](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#createPgServer_String...) ([for PostgreSQL clients](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver)).

You have started the TCP Server. If you want to use a browser, you also need to start the Web Server:

```
private static void startH2(){
    Server tcpServer = null;
    Server webServer = null;
    try {
        tcpServer = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
        System.out.println("TCP Server Port: " + tcpServer.getPort());
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
                getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test22;MODE=PostgreSQL", "sa", "");
        webServer = Server.createWebServer().start();
        System.out.println("Web Server (H2Console) Port: " + webServer.getPort());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finish");
}
```